# How to get the number of files in each directory?

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to make a bash function that would behave just like how `wc -l` behaves on multiple files to count their number of lines in counting the number of files in a set of directories. 
How `wc -l` works:

```
wc -l test.zip  tt.zip zzz.zip | sort
     17 tt.zip
   2015 test.zip
   6567 zzz.zip
   8599 total
```

How I want my function to work on files:

```
count dir1 dir2 dir3 | sort:
      1 dir1
    144 dir2
   1000 dir3
   1145 total
```

Where dir{1..3} are 3 directories and the number of files shown includes the hidden files.

What I've already done:

```
#/bin/bash
count() {
    if [ "`file -b $1`" == 'directory' ] ; then    
        echo `la "$1" | wc -l`
    else
        wc -l "$@" | sort
    fi
}
```

I can implement it with a for loop on `$@` but I'd rather find an easier solution.
If you can also help me include the size of each directory. You would make me really happy!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
find dir1 dir2 dir3 -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%h\n' | awk '{c[$0]++} END{for (dir in c) printf "%6i %s\n",c[dir],dir}' | sort -n
```

If the directories are specified in `$@`, then use:

```
find "$@" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%h\n' | awk '{c[$0]++} END{for (dir in c) printf "%6i %s\n",c[dir],dir}' | sort -n
```

#### How it works

1. `find dir1 dir2 dir3 -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%h\n'`

   This looks for all regular files in directories dir1, dir2, and dir3.  For each file found, its directory is printed.

   `-maxdepth 1` (optional) tells find not to dive into subdirectories.   `-type f` tells find to only report on regular files.  For each file found, `-printf '%h\n'` tells find to print the directory that the file is in.
2. `awk '{c[$0]++} END{for (dir in c) printf "%6i %s\n",c[dir],dir}'`

   This counts the number of times each directory appears on the input.  After all the input has been read, it prints the totals.

   We use associative array `c` to count the number of times each directory is seen.  In awk, `$0` is the contents of the current line being read.  `c[$0]` is the number of times that line has been seen so far.  `c[$0]++` increments that count by one.
3. `sort -n`

   This sorts the output in ascending order of file count.  (`-n` tells sort to sort numerically rather than alphabetically.)

#### Example

Let's suppose that we have these directories with these files:

```
$ ls dir{1..3}/*
dir1/a.txt  dir1/c.txt  dir1/e.txt      dir1/f.txt  dir2/b.txt  dir2/d.txt  dir2/f.txt  dir3/b.txt
dir1/b.txt  dir1/d.txt  dir1/file3.txt  dir2/a.txt  dir2/c.txt  dir2/e.txt  dir3/a.txt
```

Our command produces the output:

```
$ find dir1 dir2 dir3 -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%h\n' | awk '{c[$0]++} END{for (dir in c) printf "%6i %s\n",c[dir],dir}' | sort -n
     2 dir3
     6 dir2
     7 dir1
```

#### Improvement: Adding a total row

```
$ find dir1 dir2 dir3 -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%h\n' | awk '{c[$0]++} END{for (dir in c) {printf "%6i %s\n",c[dir],dir;tot+=c[dir]}; printf "%6i TOTAL",tot }' | sort -n
     2 dir3
     6 dir2
     7 dir1
    15 TOTAL
```

To suppress the printing of TOTAL if there is only one directory in the output:

```
find "$@" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%h\n' | awk '{c[$0]++} END{for (dir in c) {printf "%6i %s\n",c[dir],dir;tot+=c[dir]}; if (length(c)>1)printf "%6i TOTAL",tot }' | sort -n
```

#### Include empty directories in the output

To also include empty directories:

```
find "$@" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%h\n' | awk 'FNR==NR{c[$0]=0; next} {c[$0]++} END{for (dir in c) {printf "%6i %s\n",c[dir],dir;tot+=c[dir]}; if (length(c)>1)printf "%6i TOTAL",tot }' <(printf "%s\n" "$@") <(cat) | sort -n
```

As an example, let's consider an empty directory:

```
$ ls dir4
```

And, let's set `$@`:

```
$ set -- dir4
```

Now, let's run our code:

```
$ find "$@" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%h\n' | awk 'FNR==NR{c[$0]=0; next} {c[$0]++} END{for (dir in c) {printf "%6i %s\n",c[dir],dir;tot+=c[dir]}; if (length(c)>1)printf "%6i TOTAL",tot }' <(printf "%s\n" "$@") <(cat) | sort -n
     0 dir4
```

Let's try again with two directories:

```
$ set --  dir1 dir4
$ find "$@" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%h\n' | awk 'FNR==NR{c[$0]=0; next} {c[$0]++} END{for (dir in c) {printf "%6i %s\n",c[dir],dir;tot+=c[dir]}; if (length(c)>1)printf "%6i TOTAL",tot }' <(printf "%s\n" "$@") <(cat) | sort -n
     0 dir4
     7 dir1
     7 TOTAL
```

Comment: Thanks. It works very well. I think it's better if you edit your answer to use "$@" to match the context of the question. There are also a few tiny issue.  **1-** if you ask wc -l to count the number of lines in an empty directory. it will output 0 but your code doesn't output anything for empty directories which can be a little confusing. **2-** wc -l won't show total row if you are asking only one file. Which is pretty reasonable. but your code includes the total raw anyway.

Comment: @yukashimahuksay I have updated the answer to include examples using `$@``.  I have also added code that suppresses total when the output has only one directory.  Lastly, code is provided to list empty directories has having zero files.

Comment: I tried the last code. It only works fine if the directories are empty!

Comment: @yukashimahuksay I just checked it and you are absolutely right!  Since it's late here now, I hope you don't mind if I fix it tomorrow.

Comment: @yukashimahuksay OK.  I just updated the answer.  Try it and we'll talk tomorrow.

Comment: It duplicates the nonempty directories.

Comment: @yukashimahuksay I've tried several cases and I am not seeing any duplicated directories.  Could you provide more details?

Comment: You are right:)) my bad sorry;) I had forgotten how it was supposed to work! I was calling it on a directory containing two directories and I was expecting it to tell me how many files each of those directories had:))

Comment: Actually it has a problem! this is what I get when I call it on my Downloads foldet for example:```count Downloads/
     0 Downloads/
    31 Downloads
    31 TOTAL
```